# Naming a sum such as $\sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{x}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, notation

If we let consider a simple sum such as the following:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{n}{x}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Would it be correct to name the function that equals $\sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}{x}$ for a given upper bound, $g(n)$ or $g(x)$? I ask because the sum is written in terms of $x$ yet evaluated for inputs of $n$.

Comment: You should use $g(n)$ since the entire quantity depends only on $n$. Here $x$ is only a dummy variable inside the summation (similar to the dummy variable in integration).

Comment: On the left hand side  $x$ is a [bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) while $n$ is an open variable, so the left hand side is a function of $n$ but not of $x$

Comment: x is unimportant.  You could replace the occurrences of x with y or with k and it would not change the value of the sum.